# How can i create a listview as big as it's listitems in a layout based on weights? programmaticaly?

Tags: android, xml, listview, resize

I have a layout, it should have a listview on top thats scrollable and the listitem should be the size of the layout itself! but layout is defined with weights... and it should be like this:

[image: what i want to achieve!]

but as soon as i add the adapter with the listitems, the view gets resized! and pushes the other weight set (image)views smaller! 
And i can set the listitem (which is a seperate fragment) to a dynamic size (like 100dp) but then on different resolutions it won't be as big as the layout where it should fit in to..

my menulayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/startmenu_lv_spotlight"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_view" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/startmenu_iv_shops"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/startmenu_iv_categories"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/startmenu_iv_review"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/startmenu_iv_newmovie"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/startmenu_iv_personalactions"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my fragment of the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
alright in the fragment of the listITEM i've changed to:
```

```
schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deal_li_iv_icon_category"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deal_li_tv_text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/deal_li_iv_icon_category"
            android:text="text here"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How should i create it so that when i set the adapter, the ListView will NOT resize its bounds! and listitems will be as big as the height of the listview's bounds?

Comment: Set layout_width of ImageViews in those horizontal LinearLayouts to 0dp, not wrap_content

Comment: but the problem is, that i can not seem to work out how to set the height of the LIST ITEMS inside the LIST VIEW ! to the size of the listview.heigh...!

Comment: You have wrap_content as height.  match/fill parent is probably more of what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the height to your list adapter.
In your adapter's `getView` method, you can force the height of the layout container.

Start by adding an id to your layout container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lineLayout"
    schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deal_li_iv_icon_category"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deal_li_tv_text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/deal_li_iv_icon_category"
            android:text="text here"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The getView method of the adapter should be like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int index, View rowView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout lineLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_friend_line_adapter, (ViewGroup)rowView.findViewById(R.id.lineLayout));
    AbsListView.LayoutParams param = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(_width, _height);
    lineLayout.setLayoutParams(param);

    //example
    TextView text = (TextView) lineLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);

    return lineLayout;
}
```

Comment: how do i force height through getview??
and not the layout of the listview eh, but of the listitem! :) not sure if you meant that